# Weeknumber in google sheets seem to skip a week?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have built a kind of calendar and I am trying to add the week-numbers to it. It's one horizontal calendar in which dates refer to a dynamic calendar next to it. To get the week numbers I am using `WEEKNUM(CELL, 2)` (the `2` is to take into account that I am starting on a Monday).

But, the weeks are placed as "53, 2, 3, 4...", but in a calendar, such as Ical, it looks like this:

"53, 1, 2, 3, 4...".

So, for some reason my calendar doesn't understand that the week starts on a Monday, even though I use "2". But the weirdest part is that for week 53 it understands it should start on the Monday...

If I place the next references on Sundays it will get week "1" etc, but I am starting all my weeks on Mondays, so now the only way to get it to work is to refer week 53 on Monday (28:dec), and the rest on Sundays the week before...

Why is this happening, and how can I make it work so that Mondays start a new weeknumber, and the sequence is 53, 1, 2, 3...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the meaning of the second argument (i.e. `type`) to `WEEKNUM` in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3294949?hl=en).

> Behind the scenes, there are two week numbering "systems" used for
> this function:
>
> - System 1 - The first week of the year is considered to be the week containing January 1, which is numbered week 1.
> - System 2 - The first week of the year is considered to be the week containing the first Thursday of the year, which is numbered as week 1. System 2 is the approach specified in ISO 8601, also known as the European system for numbering weeks.

You want system 2. The only value for `type` that will use system 2 is 21. So use:

```
=WEEKNUM(CELL, 21)
```